# how to set time limit for splash screen in windows phone app 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, splash-screen

Hi I am developing one windows phone app.In this app I want to set time limit for loading in my splash screen.what happend is I am getting data(city names) from one service and insert  data into local database(SQLite)table.but what happend is in my data 2000 cities are there.these all are inserted into sqlite table.here one problem occurred.what happend is splash screen will move to main screen(2 to 3 seconds time).but in that time all the cities are not inserted.just 700 to 800 cities are inserted in table.so I want to set certain time to splash screen.how to set time for  loading.please help me.

```
   public async void insertcities()
        {
            try
            {

                 await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                {


                    var busclient = new NewReloadApp.JsonWebClient();

                    var Busresp1 = await busclient.DoRequestAsync(Url.weburl + "getCities");
                    string Busresult1 = Busresp1.ReadToEnd();
                    JArray BusjsonArray = JArray.Parse(Busresult1);

                    for (int j = 0; j < BusjsonArray.Count; j++)
                    {
                         await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.001));
                        JObject jobj = (JObject)BusjsonArray[j];

                        string id = (string)jobj["cityid"];
                        string cityname = (string)jobj["cityname"];




                        Db_Helper.Insert(new Buscities(id, cityname));

                        //  citieslist.Add(cityname);

                    }



                });

            }
```

Comment: Search for "extended splash screen" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700390.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could not setup time limit for splash screen. As I know, Splash Screen displayed before `Window.Current.Activate();`.

**EDIT**

So, you can navigate to your `StartupPage` and in `OnNavigatedTo` run your code. Before that, change your method to `Task` from `void`

```
public async Task insertcities()
```

and you can do it like that

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        await insertcities();
        // wait database logic and navigate from startup page
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(DestinationPage));
    }
```

Comment: Actually what happend is in my startup page iam   inserting data into database.how to set time to this startup page.

Comment: I hope, you inserting into database asynchronously. So, after end of execution you can navigate from you startup page. what the problem?

Comment: how can i find all the records are inserted into table

Comment: why are you doing database logic in UI thread? it's awful. also, see edit details

Comment: What happend is its take  2 minits time for loading data into database.in this time app was strucked.what should i do.please tell me how to bind data into databse without taking toomuch time.plase help me.

Comment: // wait database logic and navigate from startup page //
 I can't understand

Comment: You could make your own pseudo-Splash Screen. Don't use the normal one, and just make your own Splash Screen image and overlay it on your UI. When loading is complete, remove the splash screen.